Https proxy that support SSLKEYLOGFILE
I am currently inspecting traffic from an android app on my phone and using charles proxy, however i need to be able to inpsect https traffic in wireshark also.
is there a https proxy like charles that supports sslkeylog file or is there a way i can add support through dll?
If anyone has a solution where i can inspect packets so i can determine third party data sharing by using charles please let me know how.
i tried exporting the charles proxy to wireshark but that has been deprecated

What benefit should that get to you? Usually you decide to use a proxy xor use an sslkeylog with Wireshark. If you would manage to decrypt the traffic with Wireshark then you will see the same data as shown in the proxy. Also the traffic will be tampered as the proxy intercepts and decryots the data. Anyway if you really want to go that way simply use one of the tools that can create an sslkeylog file from a JVM - Charles is Java based and runs in a JVM. And of course capture the traffic in Wireshark.

I just recognized that mitmproxy has the option to generate an SSLKEYLOGFILE: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/65db82f4cf0c294a3e9de103c4789ba4b9b19a41/docs/src/content/howto-wireshark-tls.md
